# Prism v8.0.0.1909: aggregateCatalog and container

Tags: prism, ioc-container

How can i configure AggregateCatalog with the new version of prism?
This version of prism does not contain MefBootstrapper to configure aggregatCatalog.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Prism doesn't support MEF as dependency injection container out of the box any more. Mainly because MEF is no dependency injection container.

You should use a real dependency injection container (e.g. unity) for your dependency injection needs, MEF's a plugin framework. But you could create a bootstrapper and container extension that internally uses MEF, if you absolutely want to.

Comment: thanks for your response,
i upgrated to prism 8 and many properties does not loaded.
for exemple i have this line of code:
[ImportMany]
public List<Lazy<Iplugin,IMetadata>> Plugins
In other project i defined my class like this.
[ExportMetadata("Name1",Plugin1.MyPropety)]
[Export(typeof(IPlugin))]
public class Plugin1:IPlugin
{}
I'm missong something?

Comment: @A.Seghaier can you expand on "I updated to Prism 8"? Did you, for example, create your own `ContainerExtension`? Because there's no MEF in Prism 8, unless you add it yourself.

Comment: No, i did not create a custom containerExtension.
is there a documentation to how create it using FrameWork not core?
thank you for your help

Comment: @A.Seghaier you'll have to look at the implementation of the existing container extensions and how they are used